# Mapping Data Transfer Objects to my Model Class

Tags: c#

```
//This represents my rows in my database
public class PersonModel
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedBy{get;set;}

}


//This is what the client receives
public class PersonDto
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
}

//I have this DTO for other Views that 
//I only need to show FirstName

public class PersonFirstNameOnlyDto
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}   
}

public class Person
{
    IPerson person;
    public Person(IPerson person)
    {
        this.person=person;
    }
    public void SavePerson(PersonDto person)
    {
        this.person.SavePerson(person); 
    }
}


public interface IPerson
{
     void SavePerson(PersonDto person);
}
```

When saving a Person, I need to pass in PersonDTO to the SavePerson method but how if i want to pass the PersonFirstNameOnlyDto?. What I have in mind is to convert the PersonFirstNameOnlyDto into PersonDto(I can use AutoMapper here) or add another method to the Person class that accepts a PersonFirstNameOnlyDto. I am just thinking if there's a better way to do this, maybe using Generics but I really don't know how I can achieve it.

Regards

Comment: Why don't you just use PersonDto for full and partial data? Why a dedicated Dto for just a single field?

Comment: That's because on my SELECT query, i am just selecting specific columns from my database and map it straight to a DTO using Dapper.

Comment: And Dapper, doesn't allow you to use `PersonDTO` for mapping only `firstName`?  I ask this because `What I have in mind is to convert the PersonFirstNameOnlyDto into PersonDto` . Basically you are thinking to use PersonDTO to hold full or partial data. So, what's the point on implementing DTO per query-or-fields?

Comment: @Laiv: `Why don't you just use PersonDto for full and partial data? Why a dedicated Dto for just a single field?` While I'm not a strong proponent of this, I've heard several arguments (from lead/senior developers) that the DTO's should be separated per view so that your views are as independent from one another as they can be.

Comment: `that the DTO's should be separated per view ` So, OP is conditioning and coupling view with DB row mappers. Not a big deal better improvement. DTOs and ORM row mappers have nothing to do with each other, however, your argument points out to the contrary.

Comment: @Flater, yes that is what exactly I'm doing. I don't want to pull all the data at once then filter it on the client side that's why I have a separate DTO per view.

Comment: @Laiv, I am not implementing DTO  per field. My example is pretty simple here so let's extend it a bit further. Let's say my Person Model holds 10 fields. Some Views required me to show 5 fields of that Person Model, some Views Require all 10 of them. So in my query, I will only select the fields needed by my View then map those fields to a DTO, sure I can still use the PersonDTO throughtout my entire application but it gets more complicated as we add more columns to a table as Dapper will try to map all of them even if we just want a single column to return.

Comment: @Denden: That's not what I'm talking about. I'm only focusing on (not) reusing the same class for two different views. From a technical perspective, you could reuse the "full" class and only partially fill it (when you only want partial data). _Filtering_ data is a completely separate step that has nothing to do with the actual data you _return_.

Comment: @Flatter Sure you can do that aswell, but things get more complicated if you're into joins especially when joining big tables and you only want to show partial data.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that creating all those DTOs leads to:
1. Extra code to have to understand in that there are multiple classes for the same thing, eg a person,
2. The need for something like Dapper to handle the conversion between all these classes, 
3. Problems such as you describe in that different parts of the system need different versions of a person and tying it all together can be different.

So I'd take another approach. Just have the one class, `PersonModel` that is saved and loaded from the database. Then use interfaces to expose just the parts of that class to the views, eg:

```
public interface IPersonFirstNameOnlyDto
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}   
}

public interface IPersonDto
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
}

public class PersonModel : IPersonFirstNameOnlyDto, IPersonDto
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedBy{get;set;}
}
```

Then those views that only need the first name just refer to `IPersonFirstNameOnlyDto` etc, so they only have the properties they need exposed to them.

Comment: `Then use interfaces to expose just the parts of that class to the views` aka, [interface segregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). I don't know why, but I see it kinda "overkill". Ideally, you don't want to mix view layer components with persistence and domain layer components. So, what about implementing 2 different data models? PersonModel <- AutoMapper -> DTOs ?

Comment: @Laiv, that mixing of *view layer components with persistence and domain layer components* is an implementation detail. All the view layer knows is that it'll receive an implementation of `IPersonFirstNameOnlyDto` etc. Where that implementation came from (persistence layer, test mock etc) are unknown to it.